# How am i able to scroll down on my HTML website?

Tags: html, css

I am making a website for a school project but it doesn't let me scroll down any further, im not finished so technically i don't need to scroll down yet but im asking this for the future is anyone knows a solution (don't mind the crappy website and code this is my first HTML project)
https://chxppyz.github.io/Bjorn-Portfolio/

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Answer (score 1):

- don't use `<br/>`
- learn how to use the `p`, `h1`, `h2`, `div`
- why is there no `html` and `body` tags
- don't set a size style on `body` but on the background image